# how to find img element who not have alt attribute in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

i want to find all image element who not have alt attribute means not have alt=""
if not then how i can replace them with

Find

Replace with

i want to replace if image not have alt attribute because it is big so how i can do this in visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since alt is required attribute for img under modern schemas, visual studio should be reporting the missing ones if your doctype is set.  Tested this with XHTML 1.0 Transitional, got a warning of:

Warning 5   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'img' is missing required attribute 'alt'.